# Remove first element from jQuery collection (shift() equivalent)

Tags: jquery, arrays

In plain javascript, I can remove the first element of an array and store it in a variable like:

```
var rows = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var firstRow = rows.shift();
// now firstRow contains the first element of the original rows array,
// and rows contains the remaining elements.
```

How do I do the same thing with a jQuery collection?

```
var $rows = $('#some-table').find('> tbody > tr');
// ?
// ?
```

Comment: you can use the `splice` method in jquery

Comment: `slice()`, `splice()`, `:not(:first)`...

Comment: You could use `.get()` on jq collection then you can just apply any array method as e.g `shift()` on it. The use of `splice()` as suggested doesn't update original collection

Comment: Why you want to use jquery function while javascript has native function?

Comment: @Mohammad - I still want the resulting collections ($firstRow, and $rows) to be jQuery collections so I can run some further jquery processing on them.

Comment: You can also use the `:gt(0)` modifier in your selector to omit the first match from the collection.

Comment: @Barmar - however, I still want all the rows - I just want them split out into 1) the first row, and 2) the rest of the rows.

Answer (score 4):

```
var rows = $('tr');
var first = rows.first();
var rest = rows.slice(1);
```

Reference:

- [.first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/)
- [.slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)